# jquery function not working for trigerring position:sticky

Tags: jquery, wordpress, sticky

I have this div called "sticky" within its parent "stickyTo", there are multiple  parent divs, in my example I have only two and every scroll on that parent a sticky div comes out and will add a class on that div

```
var $sticky = jQuery('.sticky');


jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  $sticky.each(function(){
    const $this = jQuery(this);
    const stickyTop = $this.offset().top;
    const stickyBottom = stickyTop + $this.outerHeight();

    const $stickyTo = $this.parent();
    const stickyToTop = $stickyTo.offset().top;
    const stickyToBottom = stickyToTop + $stickyTo.outerHeight();

        if (stickyBottom >= stickyToBottom) {
          if (scroll < stickyTop) {
            //$sticky.addClass('fixed').removeClass('abs');
          } else {
            //$sticky.addClass('abs');
          }
        } else if (scroll > stickyToTop) {
          $sticky.addClass('stuck');
        } else if (scroll < stickyToTop) {
          $sticky.removeClass('stuck');
        }

  })

});
```

Here is My [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5eq4nmhy/2/) so show you what I am trying to do

Problem with the current code is only trigerring the 2nd div, something wrong with my `each() function` in jquery probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your each function, you should refer to the current element with $(this), not $sticky.  https://jsfiddle.net/dyc19oxL/

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  $sticky.each(function(){
  const $this = jQuery(this);
  const stickyTop = $this.offset().top;
  const stickyBottom = stickyTop + $this.outerHeight();

  const $stickyTo = $this.parent();
  const stickyToTop = $stickyTo.offset().top;
  const stickyToBottom = stickyToTop + $stickyTo.outerHeight();

    if (stickyBottom >= stickyToBottom) {
      if (scroll < stickyTop) {
        //$sticky.addClass('fixed').removeClass('abs');
      } else {
        //$sticky.addClass('abs');
      }
    } else if (scroll > stickyToTop) {
      **$(this).addClass('stuck');**
    } else if (scroll < stickyToTop) {
      **$(this).removeClass('stuck');**
    }

 })
```

Comment: Hello, thanks its working fine, so that was the problem, thanks again